# Не работает ui.textEdit.lineEdit.setText в PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Есть 3 файлика:

xyz.py тут интерфейс

```py
#xyz.py

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.13.0



from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(699, 491)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 20, 111, 51))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")

        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 440, 71, 51))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")

        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 440, 71, 51))
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")

        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(13, 120, 661, 321))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")

        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 50, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")

        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 50, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")

        self.lineEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 20, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")

        self.lineEdit_6 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 20, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName("lineEdit_6")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(530, 20, 101, 51))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 111, 51))
        self.lineEdit.setText("")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Generate Kays"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "decode"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "code"))
        self.textEdit.setHtml(_translate("Dialog", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">Your text</p></body></html>"))
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "close key 1"))
        self.lineEdit_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "close  key 2"))
        self.lineEdit_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "open key 1"))
        self.lineEdit_6.setText(_translate("Dialog", "open key 2"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Enter"))
```

main.py

```py
#main.py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from proga.xyz import Ui_Dialog
import sys

from proga.functions import genkeys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
ui = Ui_Dialog()
ui.setupUi(Dialog)
Dialog.show()



def setkys():
    global n, e, d
    n, e, d = genkeys()

# open key 1
    text = str(n)
    # как я понял ломается тут, потому что дальше код не работает
    ui.textEdit.lineEdit_6.setText(text)

# open key 2
    text2 = str(e)
    ui.lineEdit_5.setText(text)

#close key 1
    text3 = str(d)
    ui.lineEdit_2.setText(text)


ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(setkys)


sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

functions.py тут все вычисления

```py
#здесь должно все работать правильно

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from Crypto.Util.number import *
from Crypto import Random
import Crypto
import gmpy2
import sys


def genkeys():
    bits = 60
    p = Crypto.Util.number.getPrime(bits, randfunc=Crypto.Random.get_random_bytes)
    q = Crypto.Util.number.getPrime(bits, randfunc=Crypto.Random.get_random_bytes)
    fi = (p-1)*(q-1)


    n = p*q

    e = 65537
    d = (gmpy2.invert(e, fi))
    return n, e, d
```

После нажатия Generate Kays должно вывестись 3 числа в поля open key 1,open key 2 и close  key 1.
[image: Интерфейс]
Но выводится только такое сообщение 
`Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)` в командную строку.
Как это исправить?
P.S.
За кривой код прошу не винить я новичок.

Answer (score 1):

У вас хромает синтаксис.

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#from proga.xyz import Ui_Dialog     
from xyz import Ui_Dialog              # у меня все модули в текущем катклоге

#from proga.functions import genkeys
from functions import genkeys          # у меня все модули в текущем катклоге


def setkys():
# ???   global n, e, d 

    n, e, d = genkeys()

    # open key 1
    text = str(n)
    # как я понял ломается тут, потому что дальше код не работает
#    ui.textEdit.lineEdit_6.setText(text)     # ---
    ui.lineEdit_6.setText(text)               # +++

    # open key 2
    text2 = str(e)
    ui.lineEdit_5.setText(text2)              # - text

    #close key 1
    text3 = str(d)
    ui.lineEdit_2.setText(text3)              # - text


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
ui = Ui_Dialog()
ui.setupUi(Dialog)
Dialog.show()

ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(setkys)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Выглядит как опечатка.

```
ui.textEdit.lineEdit_6.setText(text) -> ui.lineEdit_6.setText(text)
```

Странно, что ваш Python не выдал верного сообщения об ошибке

```
AttributeError: 'QTextEdit' object has no attribute 'lineEdit_6'
```